# What happens when an ancestry with low-light vision is aiurvaran or dromaar heritage?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, races, vision-and-light, special-senses

With the Pathfinder 2e Remaster, all ancestries can be Aiuvarin or Dromaar (mixed elven or orcish heritage).

Aiuvaran says,

> You have elves, or possibly other aiuvarins, in your family tree. You have pointed ears and other telltale signs of elf heritage. You gain the elf trait, the aiuvarin trait, **and low light vision.** In addition, when you gain an ancestry feat, you can choose from aiuvarin and elf feats in addition to those from your ancestry,

Most versatile heritages that grant low light vision explicitly say something like

> You also gain low-light vision, **or you gain darkvision if your ancestry already has low light vision.**

...but the aiuvarin and dromaar heritages lack that language.

My question: What happens when someone from an ancestry that already has low light vision takes the aiuvarin heritage? Is there any general rule to cover this? Have the developers spoken explicitly to this at all, yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They only get low-light vision

As you wrote, this is what the heritage says.

In the case of Aiuvarin , it makes sense, as Elves themselves do not get darkvision.

For Dromaar, this is less logical, and I expect an errata soon.

Comment: Is "half-elf" an OGL term?

Comment: Half-elf isn’t an OGL term, but it’s one that carries certain implicit connotations that are uncomfortable in the context of how people of mixed heritage have been (unflatteringly) described historically, so the decision was made to move away from it.